# How to get child input type checkbox model value in parent div ng-click angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Please help me to solve this

```
<div ng-click="onAccordionClick(p[0])">

<input name="visitCompare"  type="checkbox" ng-model="visitCompare[p[0]]" >
```

How to get checkbox model value in parent click function in angular js, if I click parent div ?

Comment: please post relevant code

Comment: i am sorry sir i am new to stackoverflow my code it is not accepting plz find the below.. i want to get child input checkbox model on parent div click                                                                                                       
  <div ng-click="onAccordionClick(p[0])">

<input name="visitCompare"  type="checkbox" ng-model="visitCompare[p[0]]" > 
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your model into your function as an argument

```
<div ng-click="onAccordionClick(p[0], visitCompare[p[0]])">
```